# UITableView Performance with Realm Objects in cellForRowAt indexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I have many different sections of categories in my tableView loaded from a variable called `allProducts` which holds all my Realm objects (of type `Results<Product>`).

The correct products are being loaded in each section, however, ever since I introduced this piece of code:

```
switch productViewSegmentedControl!.selectedSegmentIndex {

    case 0:
        allProductsInSection = allProducts.filter("itemgroup = %@", allProductSections[indexPath.section])
    case 1:
        allProductsInSection = allProducts.filter("itembrand = %@", allProductSections[indexPath.section])
    case 2:
        allProductsInSection = allProducts.filter("itemtype = %@", allProductSections[indexPath.section])
    default:
        allProductsInSection = allProducts.filter("itemgroup = %@", allProductSections[indexPath.section])
    }
```

into my `cellForRowAt indexPath` method, the UI lags when scrolling at sections of the tableView where there are many items.

Each cell in the tableView holds `let product = allProductsInSection![indexPath.row]`. The `product` constant holds the properties for each item from my `Product` model class.

What can I do to increase performance of the UI?

P.S. each cell is already being reused:

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductCell") as? OrderFormViewCell
            ?? UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "ProductCell") as! OrderFormViewCell
```

Answer (score 1):

Having the `switch` statement you describe in your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method means that you're forcing Realm to re-filter the products every time a cell is about to be displayed. From the code you've shared it looks like you have a segmented control that controls which products to display. Instead of checking the segmented control's selection when preparing each cell, you should instead react to its selection changing and filter your products into an instance variable which `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` can use. This will allow Realm to filter the products only when the criteria has changed rather than every time a cell is about to be displayed.

Since you need to filter using a different value within each section of your table view, you'll want to prepare one `Results` for each section of the table view. In a method that you call when the segmented control's selection changes:

```
var productsPerSection = []
for section in 0..numberOfSections {
    let productsInSection: Results<Product>
    switch productViewSegmentedControl!.selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0:
            productsInSection = allProducts.filter("itemgroup = %@", allProductSections[section])
        case 1:
            productsInSection = allProducts.filter("itembrand = %@", allProductSections[section])
        case 2:
            productsInSection = allProducts.filter("itemtype = %@", allProductSections[section])
        default:
            productsInSection = allProducts.filter("itemgroup = %@", allProductSections[section])
    }
    productsPerSection.append(productsInSection)
}

self.productsPerSection = productsPerSection
```

Then in your `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method, use `self.productsInSection[indexPath.section]` instead of filtering to create `allProductsInSection`.

*Note: the code is an untested sketch that should hopefully communicate the general idea about the approach, but likely doesn't compile.*

Comment: How would I change the results outside of the ```cellForRow``` method while still having access to ```indexPath.section```? Could you please show me a code example?

Comment: I missed that it was used in the filter since it isn't visible in your code snippet unless scrolled to the right. Oops. You can accommodate this by pre-populating an array of `Results` indexed by `indexPath.section`, using the appropriate predicate for the given selected segment of the segmented control. This would mean you only need to filter the products once for each section rather than for every cell you display.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're telling me to do. I thought I was already populating the results using indexPath.section in my predicate. Anything done inside of the ```cellForRow``` method will be done for every single cell. I've tried putting the switch statement inside the ```numberOfRowsInSection``` method and it returns all the products that are supposed to be in the last section only.

Comment: The idea is to pull the work out of `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` and do it in response to the segmented control's selection changing, since that happens rarely. I've expanded on this approach in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check that you are dequeuing your cells properly. also if you have images in cells it will be good to clean dequeued cells there is a func called prepare for reuse clean your cells properly

Comment: I have a constant for each cell ```let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductCell")``` could you please show me how I would implement the ```prepareForReuse()``` method?

Comment: as I can see you have a custom cell class inside that class call the prepareForResue function and then try to remove anything heavy you had in the for example imageView.image = nil